# How can I write a string into a two dimensional array in C?

Tags: c

May I know how I can a write a character string into a 2D character array?
I need to read  every character in the string and put it into a 2D array.

For example:

char string[10];

I want to write all the characters in the string into a 2D array.

That means, when I read array[0][0], I should get the first character.

Update:

suppose my string is "GOODMORN"
then the 2D array should be look like this..

```
  0|1|2|3
0 G|O|O|D
1 M|O|R|N
```

Comment: And what do you get when you read array[1][[0] and array[0][1]? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: can u please specify why you need this? And what should you get when you read arr[1][0]?

Comment: i want to make a 2D array from a string..

Comment: Did you intend to put spaces between all the letters in the final array?

Comment: No never...it is just for readability

Comment: Now your question make the SENSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure `array[0]` is big enough to hold your string. Second, use `memcpy` or `strncpy` to copy the bytes of `string` into `array[0]`.

If you need to process and address each character individually, you can start by doing what memcpy does, but in a for loop:

```
#define NUM_ARRAYS 2
#define LENGTH 4

char *string = "GOODMORN";

for (arr = 0; arr < NUM_ARRAYS; arr++)
{
    for (idx = 0; idx < LENGTH; idx++)
    {
        array[arr][idx] = string[idx + (arr * LENGTH)];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Robertew: `array[0]` is the first array in your 2d array. `array[0][0]` is the first character of that first array.

Comment: @Robertw: Yep, that's what I described.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I didn't really understand what the question is about ;-)

you could simply copy the string into a location pointed to by the
array constant for the 2D array:

```
...

char array[2+1][4];
memcpy((void *)array, TEXT, sizeof(TEXT));

...
```

But this wouldn't yield auto-sizeable arrays.  Maybe you think of the following:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 char **matrixify(char text[], int vert, int horiz)
{
 int i=0;
 char **m = (char **)calloc(vert, sizeof(char*));
 do  m[i] = text + i * horiz; while(i++ < vert); 
 return m;
}

 int main()
{
 int x, y;
 /* char t[] = "this is a really long text with many words and stuff"; */
 char t[] = "GOODMORN";
 int edge = 1+(int)sqrt((double)strlen(t)); /* make a square from text */
 /* int vert = edge, horiz = edge; */ /* Auto size detection */
 int vert = 2, horiz = 4;

 char *textbuf = (char *)calloc(vert, horiz); /* not always 0-terminated */
 char **matrix = matrixify(strncpy(textbuf, t, vert*horiz), vert, horiz);

 for(y=0; y<vert; y++) {
   for(x=0; x<horiz; x++) printf("%c ", matrix[y][x]);
   printf("\n");
 }
 /*  prints:
   G O O D
   M O R N
   through matrix[i][j]   */
 return 0;
}
```

which leads to your memory layout but looks complicated 
for the problem state, *but it's C* ...

regards

rbo

Answer (score 0):

A sample program I just wrote for you to play with and see if this is what you want.
The important part is where the loops enter the game, dividing the strings character by character.

There are a lot of improvements that can be done (strncpy, the input variable being dynamic, MEMORY FREES, etc), but this is up to you.

Edit: The strncpy modification was just posted by rubber boots.

```
int main()
{
    char A[12] = "Hello World", **B;
    int B_LEN = strlen(A) / 2 + 1;

    B = (char**)malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
    B[0] = (char*)malloc(B_LEN * sizeof(char));
    B[1] = (char*)malloc(B_LEN * sizeof(char));

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < B_LEN; j++) {
            B[i][j] = A[B_LEN * i + j];
        }
        B[i][j] = '\0';
    }

    printf("%s", B[0]);
    printf("[END]\n");
    printf("%s\n", B[1]);
    printf("[END]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Obs.: The output must be like

> Hello [END]
>   World[END]

The  tag is to show you wether there are spaces, i.e., where exactly the division happened.