# Can't figure out how to assign a word from char array to another 2D char array (C lang.)

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, assign

I'm trying to save a word from one char array to another 2D char array, but for some reason I get this error: "assignment to expression with array type". Does any of You know how to fix this? I'd be extremely thankful.

I get the error at "`Ats[kiekis] = Zodis;`" and I pass arguments to function like this:

"`Palindromas(eilute, Zodis, Ats, kiekis);`"`

Function:

```
void Palindromas(char eilute[256], char Zodis[50], char Ats[20][60], int kiekis)
{
    int i, j, ilgis, l, Index;

for (i = 0; 1 == sscanf(eilute + i, "%s%n", Zodis, &l); i =+ l)
{
    ilgis = strlen(Zodis);

    Index = 1;

    for (j = 0; j < ilgis; j++)
    {
        if (Zodis[j] != Zodis[ilgis - j - 1])
        {
            Index = 0;
            kiekis++;
        }
    }

    if (Index == 1)
    {
        Ats[kiekis] = Zodis;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `strncpy(Ats[kiekis], Zodis, 59); Ats[kiekis][59] = '\0';`

Comment: In `Ats[kiekis] = Zodis;` you cannot copy a string to a simple 2-D array like this, please use `strcpy(Ats[kiekis], Zodis)` or as the above comment.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that in C strcpy function needs to be used... Thank You! By the way, could any of You explain how this line works: "(i = 0; 1 == sscanf(eilute + i, "%s%n", Zodis, &l)"? I've found it on another thread on this website, but it wasn't explained very well.

Comment: `1 == sscanf(eilute + i, "%s%n", Zodis, &l)` checks that `sscanf` returned 1. That function returns how many format specifiers it successfully read. `%n` is used to get how many characters were read so far. So this one line checks the string was read successfully, and gets its length.

Comment: Ask for [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), when the constant value is put first. The `scanf` family of functions all return the number of items successfully converted. The programmer is right to do this - absolutely essential when reading input data. Although it is actually wrong: there are ***two*** input items. So `2== ...`

Comment: @WeatherVane `%n` is special. `1 ==...` is correct.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks missed that. I was wondering why you deleted a similar comment.

Comment: Thank You all for the explanation!

Comment: you should check out @nmichaels answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008029/how-can-i-write-a-string-into-a-two-dimensional-array-in-c#5008067